# Why does React/Redux reset all event handlers, even if `state` is unchanged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

To create a `onClick` event that logs the id of a component, I use this function:

```
const onClick = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
};

const Bar = ({id, text}) => (<div onClick={onClick.bind(null,id)}>{id}: {text}</div>);
```

This already works correctly, it logs the `id` of the item I click.

However, according to [`Perf.printDOM()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html) React apparently touches every node with this handler and creates a new one when the `state` is updated, even if its unchanged.

Is this intended design or an error in my design? Do I misunderstand what's happening? Would it be premature optimization to find a way to skip this?

[Here is a Jsbin for demonstration](http://jsbin.com/tufatawafi/1/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new event handler every time the component is rendered (which is going to happen every time an event gets handled or state changes or the like). For that reason alone I'd advise against calling `bind()` inside a functional component, and using either a standard component defined using `React.createClass` or using an ES6 class inherited from `Component` instead.

Essentially you should design your components assuming that `render()` will be called many times, and to avoid allocating or binding as much as possible in that method.

React also has it's own event handling system that mimics the native DOM one, but works a bit differently under the covers. It handles all events at the root component level, and determines which component's handlers to fire based on the source of the event. The [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) are a great place to dig in to how this system works, and of course there always the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/src/renderers/dom/client).